# SQL syntax checkbox result

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-2, pyrocms

I have a problem with a SQL query.
I'm getting the result of 2 checkboxes selection. This give me one array.
I need to query my DB in order to see if there is a statement corresponding to one of the attribute in the array. But I must search in two columns.

Here is my code :

```
    $ids = join(',',$param);  
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('default_profiles');
    $test = " 'motivation' IN (".$ids.") OR 'envies' IN (".$ids.")";
    $this->db->where($test);
```

Here is my error : 
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; Unknown column ' 'motivation' IN (option3,option3) OR 'envies' IN (option3,option3)' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`default_profiles`) WHERE ` 'motivation' IN (option3,option3) OR 'envies' IN (option3,option3)

If i remove the or statement it works but it only search in one column.

If someone can help me it would be great !

Update with single quote
EDIT : I think the problem comes from the quote juste after the WHERE but I don't know how to delete it

Comment: You should quote both motivation and envies with backticks; could you also edit your question and add what you get when you `echo ($test)`?

Comment: do you have any numbers in `IN()` it seems taht `$ids` are empty that is why you get this error. Check `$param` variable.

Comment: my param variable contains  option3option3motivation

Comment: the echo test give  'motivation' IN (option3,option3) OR 'envies' IN (option3,option3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not accept single quotes for quoting table or column names, but expects backticks.
You should check, if you have got any ids, otherwise you may run into trouble.

#### PHP 5.3:

```
if (!empty($param)) {
    $db = $this->db;
    array_walk($param, function(&$value) use ($db) {
        $value = "'" . $db->escape($value) . "'";
    });
    $ids = join(',', $param);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('default_profiles');
    $test = " `motivation` IN ($ids) OR `envies` IN ($ids)";
    $this->db->where($test);
    // ...
}
```

#### PHP 5.4:

```
if (!empty($param)) {
    array_walk($param, function(&$value) {
        $value = "'" . $this->db->escape($value) . "'";
    });
    $ids = join(',', $param);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('default_profiles');
    $test = " `motivation` IN ($ids) OR `envies` IN ($ids)";
    $this->db->where($test);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thx a lot. I still get an error but not the same "Unknown column 'option3' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`default_profiles`) WHERE `motivation` IN (option3,option2) OR `envies` IN (option3,option2)"

Comment: in fact, if I select an option wich does not yet appear in my column I give this error. Do you know what can I do ?

Comment: If your ids are strings you need to quote them. I assumed integers. Updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I can't do a this->db->escape, this give  Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: Ok, then you're still using PHP5.3; `$this` became available in anonymous functions in 5.4. Adding changes to my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have the same error as before : check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option3'',''Développer mes connaissances'') OR `envies` IN (''option3'',''Déve' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`default_profiles`) WHERE `motivation` IN (''option3'',''Développer mes connaissances'') OR `envies` IN (''option3'',''Développer mes connaissances'') Because "option3" does not appear in my databse. If I only have value which are in my db it works. This is strange because if I delete the "or" statement it works.  Thx for your time

Comment: Obviously the `escape()` function  does not work correctly, since it - despite its name - adds quotes already. Changing `$value = "'" . $this->db->escape($value) . "'";` to `$value = $this->db->escape($value);` should solve that for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, $value = $db->escape($value); works like a charm !